# Ubuntu 17.10 - DNS query via TCP not working

Tags: 17.10, dns, dnscrypt-proxy

I'm using DNSCrypt-proxy:

```
me@nb:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.2.1


me@nb:~$ nslookup ya.ru
Server:     127.0.2.1
Address:    127.0.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 87.250.250.242

me@nb:~$ ping ya.ru
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=31.3 ms
^C
--- ya.ru ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.320/31.320/31.320/0.000 ms
```

now I'm setting **TCPOnly on** into /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.conf

```
me@nb:~$ sudo service dnscrypt-proxy restart
me@nb:~$ nslookup ya.ru
Server:     127.0.2.1
Address:    127.0.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 87.250.250.242

me@nb:~$ ping ya.ru
ping: ya.ru: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: @muru I believe ping must use system getHostByName function.

Comment: @muru this means nothing. While detecting host ip it must send UPD DNS request first **and fallback to TCP DNS request if something wrong with UDP**exatly like nslookup do :)

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5966#section-4